# What does the ? or ! at the end of an Elixir function do?

Tags: elixir

What does the `!` or `?` mean at the end of Elixir functions mean?   Is this something special to the language or just to a particular package?

```
ExAws.S3.list_buckets() |> ExAws.request!()
```

Comment: Those characters are actually part of the name of the function - which is unusual in most programming languages - thus it can raise surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [Naming Conventions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/naming-conventions.html) in Elixir.

`!` calls [Trailing bang](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/naming-conventions.html#trailing-bang-foo)

> A trailing bang (exclamation mark) signifies a function or macro where failure cases raise an exception.

`?` calls [Trailing question mark](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/naming-conventions.html#trailing-question-mark-foo)

> Functions that return a boolean are named with a trailing question mark.

Comment: if you want to know more about style guide, search in https://github.com/ style guide elixir...